# Python 3, super.__del__()

Tags: python, python-3.x, destructor, super

I have a `__del__` method in a class I've defined, to delete some C++ objects created by calling C++ new in a ctypes interface. I want to delete these objects when an instance of my class is destroyed. I have a fragment of the class shown here:

```
class Graph(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #list of objects created by calls to ctypes to create pointers to C++ objects which are instantiated with C++ new 
        self.graphs = []

    def __del__(self):
        print("in delete method")
        for graph in self.graphs:
            # call the C++ delete to free the storage used by this graph
            myctypes.graphDelete(graph)
        super().__del__()
```

When an instance of my Graph class is deleted, the `__del__` method is called and I see my print statement and when I set a breakpoint in the destructor method in the C++ code, as expected, it deletes the object. However, when my `__del__` method calls `super().__del__()`, I get the error message:

```
super().__del__()
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__del__'
```

How do I ensure that the parent class (QtCore.QObject) is deleted if I define my own `__del__` method in the child class or will the parent class be deleted automatically?

Comment: Please try `super(Graph, self).__del__()` and `QtCore.QObject.__del__(self)`. This should make no difference, but maybe it works.

Comment: Thanks Kay, I just tried both of those and I still get the attribute error.

Comment: @inwhack, I believe that the garbage collector will do its job, cleanup up unused instances / variables

Answer (score 6):

The role of `__del__` is not to delete the object: it is called *before* the object is automatically deleted. Therefore it's fine if your parent class doesn't define `__del__`. Feel free not to call `super().__del__()` if it's bugging you.

For the record, the reason why objects don't have a default `__del__` is that objects with `__del__` were not garbage collected in case of reference cycles (until Python 3.4). For more information, read the documentation for [gc.garbage in Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/gc.html#gc.garbage) and for [gc.garbage in Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/gc.html#gc.garbage).

Comment: Can you expand on the second paragraph? I don't understand. Does that mean that if you have a `def __del__(self):`  in your class that the object will not be garbage collected? Thanks! (ps. Mostly in regards to Python 2.7)

Comment: If you have a reference cycle and one of the objects in the cycle has `__del__`, then the objects are never disposed. See [gc.garbage in 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/gc.html#gc.garbage) and [gc.garbage in 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/gc.html#gc.garbage)

Answer (score 4):

The class you're deriving from doesn't have `__del__()`. So trying to call it is an error.

Now, if you expect your class to be used in a multiple inheritance scenario, the next class in the method resolution order (MRO) might not actually be your class's parent. And that class, whatever it is, might have a `__del__()` method. So, if you're concerned about that case, you could use `try` and swallow the `AttributeError`, or use `hasattr()`, or use `getattr()` with a dummy lambda as a default value.

Here's an example of each:

```
# there is a minor bug here, can you guess what it is?
try:
    super().__del__(self)
except AttributeError:
    pass

# better versions of the above
s = super()
try:
    s.__del__
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    s.__del__(self)

# alternative 2
s = super()
if hasattr(s, "__del__"): 
    s.__del__(self)

# alternative 3
getattr(super(), "__del__", lambda self: None)(self)
```

Comment: The "minor bug" to which I refer in the code comment is that we are not catching *only* the `AttributeError` caused by the attribute lookup on your superclass. In other words, if `__del__` exists on the next class in the MRO, but calling it raises `AttributeError`, this error will be incorrectly swallowed rather than being reported. But 60% of the time, it works every time.

Answer (score 0):

From the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__),

> Called when the instance is about to be destroyed. This is also called a finalizer or (improperly) a destructor. If a base class has a **del**() method, the derived class’s **del**() method, if any, must explicitly call it to ensure proper deletion of the base class part of the instance.

Correct me if I'm wrong. If the base class doesn't provide `__del__`, you don't have to call it. Catching `AttributeError` and ignoring it is a good way.

Comment: I think this is correct. It seems in Python,  there is not an empty `__del__` for any class as default. It only exists when you defined it.